# FFmpeg license for transcoding without distribution

Tags: ffmpeg

I am making a website (in a commercial context) where users can upload videos to our server
naturally that causes problems with browser compatibility. the solution would be to transcode them using FFmpeg on the server.
the problem is i have been reading on FFmpeg and it's license and i am very confused, does the use of FFmpeg on the server count as distribution ? and that is before talking about patented code.
if it is not possible to do it without risking the entire company in legal disputes. are there any alternatives that can be used ?
thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

> does the use of FFmpeg on the server count as distribution ?

No. "use" and "distribution" are specifically different things in a legal context. The FFmpeg license (LGPL) only limits distribution rights; it gives you the "[freedom to run](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html#run-the-program)" (this is freedom 0) which means you can use it in any you want. That freedom is explicit and intentional.

> and that is before talking about patented code.

As for patents: ask a lawyer.

> are there any alternatives that can be used

Not really, most alternatives end up using FFmpeg internally.